# Check select element for value, multiply the value in another element by a fixed number

Tags: jquery

I want to multiply the value in an element by 0.62137119 if a selection box is set to 'Miles', then update the value. This is so I can create a simple km to mile conversion.

I would also like to embed this in an existing $(':input').on function. I'm new to js so sorry if my attempt looks like I don't know what I'm talking about.

html
    `<select name="measurement" name="measurement" id="measurement">
    <optgroup label="measurement">
    <option value="">Please Select Imperial or Metric</option>
    <option value="kilometres" selected="selected">kilometres</option>
    <option value="miles">miles</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>`

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="distance" readonly="readonly" name="distance" value="10" class="value" />
```

js

```
$(':input').on('input change', function (event) {
//do first function;
//do second function;
function (){
var measurement = $('#measurement');
var distance = $('#distance');
if(measurement == "miles"){
$('#distance').val(distance * 0.62137119)]);
    }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJYw7/1/

Edit: It should also work vice versa (so divide by 0.62137119 if kilometers is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code fixed:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/SJYw7/8/)

JS Code:

```
$('select').on('change', function (event) {
    // Get both values
    var measurement = $('#measurement').val();  
    var distance = $('#distance').val();
    // intialize cnonverted value to zero
    var value = 0;
    // if --> to miles
    if (measurement == "miles") 
        value = distance * 0.62137119; 
     // else means --> to kms.
     else
        value = distance / 0.62137119;

    $("#distance").val(value.toFixed(8)); // round of to 8 digits of precision and set
});
```

You had many syntax errors and set `<input>` to read-only, which I removed to do necessary checks. You can add it back if required

P.S. Don not use `input` event as it will fire every time user presses **any** key, so pressing `127` will not yield the desired output. As you said, use `change` on `select` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. What about listening for that specific select to change?